# Keep priority after update with AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have a database with exercises, and each exercise has a field userId which references to the user that the exercise belongs to. I would want to retrieve every exercise that belongs to the current user, so I have assigned a priority to each exercise which corresponds to the userId, I can then retrieve every exercise for a specific user like this:

```
            collection: function(user_id) {
                return angularFireCollection(new Firebase(FBURL+'/exercises').startAt(user_id).endAt(user_id));
            },
```

Which is called from a controller like this:

```
        $scope.findExercises = function() {
            $scope.exercises= Exercises.collection($scope.auth.id);
        }
```

The problem is, when I update an exercise, the priority seems to be removed since it no longer turns up in the collection. The exercise is updated via the realtime binding angularFire(). How can I make updates and maintain the priority, or reset the priority?

Comment: Hi @Nait, have you seen this blog post on performing common SQL queries with Firebase? https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html

Comment: Yes @Sara, I found that post shortly after I published this question, which made me realise that I was trying to design the database with SQL in mind.

Comment: sounds good. You can email support@firebase.com if you have any more questions.